# UseEffect won't use updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react function which is supposed to be my header. This header shall change its background color after reaching a button on scroll.

To do so I use a scroll event listener and track its position in relation to the button. This works fine for `setTransparent(false)`, but not for `setTransparent(true)`: 
 **Logging `transparent` inside of the listener returns `true` even after setting it to `false` inside of the first if-statement.**

How so? What's the best practice here?

```
const [transparent, setTransparent] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector(".hero-button");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
        const {bottom} = button.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (transparent && bottom <= 0) {
            setTransparent(false);
        } else if (!transparent && bottom > 0) {
            setTransparent(true);
        }
    });
}, [])
```

Setting the dependency to `transparent` will make it work, but this will add even listener every time it updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `transparent` variable in the effect callback only references the value on the initial render, which is always `true`. You can fix it by re-adding the scroll listener whenever `transparent` changes, and return a cleanup function that removes the prior handler:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const button = document.querySelector(".hero-button");
    const scrollHandler = () => {
        const { bottom } = button.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (transparent && bottom <= 0) {
            setTransparent(false);
        } else if (!transparent && bottom > 0) {
            setTransparent(true);
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
    // DON'T FORGET THE NEXT LINE
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);
}, [transparent]);
```

Another option would be to use a ref instead of `useState` for transparent (or, in addition to `useState` if `transparent` changes needs to result in re-rendering).